# Subset top entries based on two criteria in R

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

So I have a dataframe something like this...

```
status occupation
1      A
1      A
1      B
0      C
0      A
1      B
0      B
0      A
1      A
0      D
0      D
0      D
0      D
```

And I condense to get counts as follows:

```
counts <- df %>%
   group_by(status, occupation) %>%
   summarize(count = n()) %>%
   group_by(occupation) %>%
   mutate(pct = percent(count/sum(count)))
```

Which gives me:

```
status   occupation  count   pct
1         A          3       60%
1         B          2       66%
0         A          2       40%
0         B          1       33%
0         C          1       100%
0         D          4       100%
```

So I would like to create a subset of this exact dataframe of the occupations with the highest counts. So let's say the top two occupations with the highest counts.

But this is irrespective of status.

Final outcome desired:

```
status   occupation  count   pct
1         A          3       60%
0         A          2       40%
0         D          4       100%
```

Notice that this subset is the occupations which have the highest total count, irrespective of the status. So I need a subset of the 2 highest count occupations and then the new subset has the breakdown in it.

Comment: Add after `mutate(...)` this `%>% top_n(3, count)`?

Comment: Needs to be ungrouped but still doesn't work, see @Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add:

```
counts <- df %>%
  group_by(status, occupation) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  group_by(occupation) %>%
  mutate(pct = percent(count/sum(count)),
         occ_count = sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice_max(., order_by = occ_count, n = 3) %>% 
  select(-occ_count)
```

Comment: did not work / that didn't even reduce to three entries

Comment: You have a tie where `count == 2` so you should expect 4 entries.

Comment: That doesn't exactly work either. The dilema of the tie must be overcome. I need to get the occupations that have the higher total counts, irrespective of the status.

Comment: So Occupations A and D are the highest count totals, no matter status, so I need to preserve their breakdown of status after subsettng

Comment: @JohnThomas I updated the post - this should get you what you want.

Comment: @Matt I think this is it, however is there something specific I need to do if I wanted to up the number of occupations to say 10 or another number? Why is n = 3 in the case where I want top 2?